# ipad table occupying whole screen but not designed to do that?

Tags: ipad, uitableview

In my iPad app, I'm designing a table view that uses a check box in table cells, but the table is occupying the whole screen even though is just a small table in Interface Builder.

What am I doing wrong? Why is this table taking up the whole screen?
A link to my little project is here.
[here](http://hyperprogram.com/TableCellCheckBox.zip)

---

ok, sorry for the noobnes!!
so I fixed by changing my view controller duuhhhh
from UITableViewController to
UIViewController

but now I have another problem!!
the

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

gives me an error!
so how can I fix to render properly the change of the button  with out going back to UITableViewController!

thank you!  Wright CS!!

another thing please,

to allow the if to compare if the cell was hit, I have a sintax problem>

> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath 
>     { 
>     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

```
// here PROBLEM
if ([[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Sports"] )
{
    NSLog(@"perra");
    //Sports *sports = [[Sports alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sports" bundle:nil]; 
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:sports animated:YES];
    //[sports release];

    //sports = [[Sports alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sports" bundle:nil];

    //anima
    //[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    //[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    //[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
    //                     forView:self.view cache:YES];

    //[self.view addSubview:sports.view];
    //[UIView commitAnimations];



}

else if ([[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Entertainment"] )
{
    NSLog(@"parra");
    // *blue = [[Blue alloc] initWithNibName:@"Blue" bundle:nil]; 
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:blue animated:YES];
    //[blue release];
}

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your table is "full screen" is because it is a `UITableViewController`. Make it a `UIViewController` and then you can programmatically set the frame, or build it in Interface Builder.

```
@interface TableCellViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblCustomCell;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tblCustomCell;

@end
```

and in your .m, `@synthesize tblCustomCell;` and don't forget to connect everything in IB.

then if you need to call `reloadData`, use:

```
    [tblCustomCell reloadData];
```

Comment: hi thanks so much, is fixed but how to avoid the error for the reloadData?,  thanks a lot!

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. You need to connect the table in IB.

Comment: awesome, now another question haha, how to implement the if hit cell I have a mistake in my sintax bro, please how to fix this?? thanks